# I don't understand why I need to input "q" for n times of question generate, to quit program

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, recursion

I dont know why I have to input `q` n times of question generated to quit the program, what should I do so that the program closes instantly when I input `q` only once?

```py
    greetings = input("Hello, what should i call you? ")
    
    
    def generate_again_or_quit():
        while True:
            option = input("Press any key to generate another question or Q to exit" ).lower()
            if option == "q":
                break
            generate_questions()
            
    def generate_questions():
        print(random_questions_dict.get((random.randint(1, 30))))
        generate_again_or_quit()
    while True:
        greetings2 = input("Do you want me to generate some questions "+greetings+"?").lower()
        
        if greetings2 == "yes":
            generate_questions()
            break
            
        elif greetings2 == "no":
            print("See you later...")
            break
        else:
            print("Please answer with yes or no")
            continue
```

Comment: the ''' greetings = input("Hello, what should i call you? ")''' is the first part of the code

Comment: Because your solution uses both recursion *and* iteration. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Hint: pick iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, pick iteration or recursion. Here's a recursion example for your case

```
import random

random_questions_dict = {1: "why", 2: "what", 3: "when", 4: "which", 5: "how"}

def generate_questions():
    print(random_questions_dict.get((random.randint(1, 5))))
    option = input("Press any key to generate another question or Q to exit" ).lower()
    if option == "q":
        return
    generate_questions()


greetings = input("Hello, what should i call you? ")

while True:
    greetings2 = input("Do you want me to generate some questions "+greetings+"?").lower()
    
    if greetings2 == "yes":
        generate_questions()
        break
        
    elif greetings2 == "no":
        print("See you later...")
        break
    else:
        print("Please answer with yes or no")
        continue
```